Expectation of a binomial random variable raised to a power
I have this problem:
If $X$ follows a Binomial distribution with parameters $ n = 15 $ and $ p = \frac{1}{4} $, calculate $E[X]$, $E[X^2]$ and $ E[X^6] $.
Computing $E[X]$ and $E[X^2]$ is fairly simple as we get to the binomial formula, but I cannot figure out how to calculate $E[X^6]$. Can someone please help me ?

Do you know any moment generating function?

one important step is to find moment generating function of binomial (if you want to write down complete answer)

I do not know much about the moment generating function for binomial. Could you give me some more insights please?

This is an explicit distribution!  There are only $16$ values $X^6$ might take, and it is easy to compute their probabilities.  It is then easy to compute the mean.  Sure, if you want to have a closed formula for general $n$ you need to work harder, but you were only asked about $n=15$ and the direct computation is straight forward.

@johnyy, please look at this, in the Wiki page, the definition and the moment generating function of binomial distribution is given.

@lulu do you calculatind this brute by replacing the variables with their actual values?
$\sum_{x=1}^{n} x^6 \binom{n}{x} p^x q^{n-x}$

Yes, exactly.  $\quad$.

@lulu the moment generating function is a more direct approach.

@JeanMarie  I don't see how.   The given problem, for a fixed small $n$, can be solved almost instantly by direct computation.   Sure, if you want to generalize $n$, it is better to have a more powerful tool.
